VSCode suddenly not running new code and giving old, running codes in Parrot OS
Recently, my VSCode was working fine, until today, where I had written a program in cpp and when i went to run it, it simply didn't run, and gave this error. error message received
Moreover, any old programs that i had written are no longer working, showing this error. error message 2 received
This is the first time I've experienced an error like this. I've tried changing the shell as i thought it may have been an error of using the wrong shell type, but to no avail. I also tried updating VSCode to the latest version, but the issue still persists.
FYI, I use Parrot OS 6.9.7
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.
